# Variable price for mobile app for various countries

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mobile-application

Can I provide a different price (not just a converted currency) for my app for different countries stores?

p.s.1 I want to do this for apple's app store and google's play store. 
p.s.2 I don't want to upload a separate app for each country's store. I want it to be the same app for all countries but with different prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for ios

SKProduct has a property "priceLocale" , which provide you local price of product (based on device local by default).

For each in-app purchase item you have to create a separate SKProduct object with a valid "productIdentifier".

```
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:bundleID]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
```

Comment: Thanks.

1- Will this allow me to specify that the price for people in Germany is equivalent to 6 $ while for France it's equivalent to 5 $?

2- Is there a non-programmatic way (something from itunes connect for example)?

Comment: 1. - Yes. Each market have specific prices. This will provide you price in local currency for the market. You dont need to convert it.    2. - No (btw local price is provided by App Store).